# What to put in the Discussion section of a paper in this case?

Tags: publications, writing

From what I know in the Discussion section, it is recommended to establish a comparison between one's proposal with what other authors have done. For example, in the CS field, I have seen that this is not so troublesome, for instance, if I am proposing a model of ML that predicts diabetes if my article uses the same dataset. So, in this case, I can compare similar methodologies or similar results obtained by other authors.

However, I have what to do when the dataset that I am using is only suited for a determined environment. For example, let's imagine that I want to predict the crime rate of certain portions of a city, and I live in London, but I found many articles about how to predict the crime rate in New Delhi. In this situation, if the two datasets are different, how can I write a Discussion section? I cannot compare my research with others (the New Delhi example) because my dataset is different. I have stumbled upon this trouble with some localized datasets, any advice?
Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you discuss your results compared to another data set?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BryanKrause, maybe I might be wrong but I believe that the comparison will not be quite fair. Some datasets, for example in ML, present some internal patterns that made them easier to classify than others.

Comment: Ah, is this a paper where your result is just "our performance was XYZ%" and you aren't actually interested in the results otherwise? Either way I think this sort of thing is typically better discussed with an advisor than on StackExchange, because it's specific to your particular research rather than helpful for a broader audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to discuss the results per se - that indeed doesn't necessarily make sense given the different datasets. However, you can discuss the methodology. For example - why did you decide to use algorithm X while the other paper used algorithm Y? Why did you decide to remove certain features that the other dataset didn't? DId you make any modelling decisions that go against some other papers? What do you think the ethical implications of these predictions are and how does that align with research on ethics in machine learning.

Comparing only the accuracy (or whatever metric you've picked) isn't really valuable in this case indeed, so look at other things you did.